# using Flutter to check a specific field value of a user

Tags: flutter

how can i easily check a specific field - value of a relative user who has already been saved on firestore . so for example on firebase it has been recorded that the user's 'role'(field) is that of a 'client'(value)

this is a code snippet i primarliry used to chek the user:

```
 void checkRole(String name, String uid) async {
await firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get().then((role) {
  if (role.data()!["client"] == true) {
    print("true");
  } else {
    print("false");
  }
});
```

im trying to call checkRole() on the snippet below , except I got an error saying "2 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found":

```
  InkWell(
            onTap: () => {authController.checkRole()},
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 13.0, top: 15.0),
              child: Row(
                children: const [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 9),
                  Text(
                    "check role",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: in your method, you are expecting two parameters. that should be given

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused because your method "checkRole" expects 2 arguments name and uid. But when you are calling the method authController.checkRole(), you are not passing any argument.

Since the function checkRole doesn't use name you could remove that.

```
void checkRole(String uid) async { 
  await firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get().then((role) {
  if (role.data()!["client"] == true) {
      print("true");
  } else {
      print("false");
  }
});
```

And

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () => {authController.checkRole('youruid')},
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 13.0, top: 15.0),
          child: Row(
            children: const [
              Icon(
                Icons.person,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 9),
              Text(
                "check role",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined your check role function with two parameters. It should be passed while calling the function.

```
InkWell(
   onTap: () => authController.checkRole('your name', 'your uid'),
   child: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 13.0, top: 15.0),
       child: Row(
           children: const [
              Icon(Icons.person),
              SizedBox(width: 9),
              Text(
                  "check role",
                  style: TextStyle(
                     fontSize: 16,
                  ),
                 ),
              ],
        ),
    ),
),
```

And in your check role function, there is no use of the name parameter. So you can remove it and call accordingly.

Comment: so i need more clarity , im confused as to what do i actually pass into the checkRole() i going to call ,- say for instance in the place where i'm meant to pass for the 'you uid' parameter , should i put the actual uid number or there's another way i should do this?

Comment: actual uid you need to pass.